# Fastest way to select distinct values from list based on two properties

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, distinct

I have a this list:

```
List<myobject> list= new List<myobject>();

list.Add(new myobject{name="n1",recordNumber=1}); 
list.Add(new myobject{name="n2",recordNumber=2}); 
list.Add(new myobject{name="n3",recordNumber=3});
list.Add(new myobject{name="n4",recordNumber=3});
```

I'm looking for the fastest way to select distinct objects based on recordNumber, but if there is more than one object with same recordNumber(here recordNumber=3), I want to select object base on its name.(the name provided by paramater)

thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "...but if there is more than one object with same recordNumber, I want to select object base on its name."?

Comment: sure, if we have to object with same record number(recordNumber=3), I Should select the object that its name is "n3". this vale ("n3") is a paramater and it should be use for all duplicate objects.

Comment: Do you mean "the first name by alphabetical order"?

Comment: No, public myobject Find(string name) 
{ 
} we use name parameter for duplicat objects.

Comment: Which would mean that you could miss objects if the duplicate record numbers don't have a name with the passed in parameter?

Comment: yes, with duplicate, I only need the object with a name equals to the parameter.

Comment: What if there are duplicates but none of them have the name passed as the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are really after something like:

```
Dictionary<int, List<myobject>> myDataStructure;
```

That allows you to quickly retrieve by record number.  If the `List<myobject>` with that dictionary key contains more than one entry, you can then use the name to select the correct one.

Note that if your list is not terribly long, an O(n) check that just scans the list checking for the recordNumber and name may be *fast enough*, in the sense that other things happening in your program could obscure the list lookup cost.  Consider that possibility before over-optimizing lookup times.

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately I have a dll that returns a list of object as I said in question. I’m not sure creating dictionary from list is the fastest way.

Comment: @salel: That depends on how frequently you will search for elements vs. how frequently you will rebuild the list, and on how large the list is.  Searching an unordered list will always be O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the LINQ way of doing this:

```
Func<IEnumerable<myobject>, string, IEnumerable<myobject>> getDistinct =
    (ms, n) =>
        ms
            .ToLookup(x => x.recordNumber)
            .Select(xs => xs.Skip(1).Any()
                ? xs.Where(x => x.name == n).Take(1)
                : xs)
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .ToArray();
```

I just tested this with a 1,000,000 randomly created `myobject` list and it produced the result in 106ms. That should be fast enough for most situations.

Comment: thanks, I will use these solutions and check it which one is faster in my environment.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<myobject> list = new List<myobject>();

            list.Add(new myobject { name = "n1", recordNumber = 1 });
            list.Add(new myobject { name = "n2", recordNumber = 2 });
            list.Add(new myobject { name = "n3", recordNumber = 3 });
            list.Add(new myobject { name = "n4", recordNumber = 3 });

            //Generates Row Number on the fly
            var withRowNumbers = list 
                    .Select((x, index) => new 
                            {
                                Name = x.name,
                                RecordNumber = x.recordNumber,
                                RowNumber = index + 1
                            }).ToList();

            //Generates Row Number with Partition by clause
            var withRowNumbersPartitionBy = withRowNumbers
                    .OrderBy(x => x.RowNumber)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.RecordNumber)
                    .Select(g => new { g, count = g.Count() })
                    .SelectMany(t => t.g.Select(b => b)
                    .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, t.count), (j, i) => new { Rn = i, j.RecordNumber, j.Name}))
                    .Where(i=>i.Rn == 1)
                    .ToList();
            //print the result
            withRowNumbersPartitionBy.ToList().ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine("Name =  {0}   RecordNumber = {1}", i.Name, i.RecordNumber));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class myobject
    {
        public int recordNumber { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Result:**

```
Name =  n1   RecordNumber = 1
Name =  n2   RecordNumber = 2
Name =  n3   RecordNumber = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a method to do this?

```
List<myobject> list= new List<myobject>();

list.Add(new myobject{name="n1",recordNumber=1}); 
list.Add(new myobject{name="n2",recordNumber=2}); 
list.Add(new myobject{name="n3",recordNumber=3});
list.Add(new myobject{name="n4",recordNumber=3});

public myobject Find(int recordNumber, string name)
{
    var matches = list.Where(l => l.recordNumber == recordNumber);

    if (matches.Count() == 1)
        return matches.Single();

    else return matches.Single(m => m.name == name);
}
```

This will - of course - break if there are multiple matches, or zero matches. You need to write your own edge cases and error handling!

Comment: Linq does not make things faster.  If anything, the extra layer of abstraction can make things ever so slightly slower.

Comment: not exactly. I don't have the record number, I only have the name, if there are more object with same recordNumber, then I should use name for selecting the object.

Answer (score 0):

If the name and recordNumber combination is guaranteed to be unique then you can always use [Hashset](http://theburningmonk.com/2011/03/hashset-vs-list-vs-dictionary/).

You can then use RecordNumber and Name to generate the HashCode by using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode).

```
class myobject 
{

     //override GetHashCode
     public override int GetHashCode()
     {
        unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
        {
           int hash = 17;
           // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
           hash = hash * 23 + recordNumber.GetHashCode();
           hash = hash * 23 + name.GetHashCode();
           return hash;
         }
     }
     //override Equals      
}
```